# React show image if state is set to true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to hide an image by default and only show it when element is hovered. I've been able to set the default state etc.. Only issue is creating an if statement that will show and hide the image.

This is the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

import Eyecon from '../../static/eye.svg';


class Item extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.displayName = 'Item';
        this.handleHover = this.handleHover.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            hover: false
        };
    }
    mouseOver() {
        this.state.hover = true;
    }
    mouseOut() {
        this.state.hover = false;
    }
    handleHover() {
        console.log("hover");
    }
    render() {
      const { item, i } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="grid-box">
                <img src={Eyecon}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Item;
```

I've tried a few things, but also want to see what the best practice is.

Thanks for your time

Comment: I'm fairly new to React but I think you can do:                               {this.state.hover &&
  <img src={Eyecon}/>
}

Comment: note that `state` is immutable, which means you shouldn't modify it directly by calling `this.state.hover = true`. Try instead `this.setState({ hover: true })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways, I would do it like this:

```
render() {
  const { item, i } = this.props;
    return (
        <div className="grid-box">
            {this.state.hover ? (
                <img src={Eyecon} />
            ) : null}
        </div>
    )
}
```

But you could also abstract the image rendering into a separate function and not return anything when needed.

Sitenote: You shouldn't mutate the state directly. Use the `this.setState()` function. Otherwise the component will not be re-rendered.

Also, may I ask why you're not just using css `:hover` to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: why `null` and not just `{ this.state.hover && <img /> }` ?

Comment: @azium - That code snippet is much less readable than either of the answers posted.

Comment: @azium I consider mine more readable, but it's a matter of opinion. I do recall someone having problems with your way of doing things, where a React update caused it to render incorrectly. Can't remember what the exact problem was though

Comment: I find the extra noise to make it less readable. uneeded parens + ternaries in jsx are way more confusing then they need to be.

Comment: But ternaries are more explicit. It reads like "is hover true? then this, otherwise null". Yours reads like "is hover and image true?". Of course, it's not too difficult to get used to that pattern if it's used a lot in an app. Also, in this case I think you could get rid of the parens if you really wanted to.

Comment: Guards and defaults are so common in JS. They're not 'and' and 'or', they're 'then' and 'otherwise'. It's true the boolean operators are overloaded here though.

Answer (score 0):

I typically like to handle conditional displaying of content in helper functions, like so:

```
function renderImage() {
    const { hover } = this.state;

    if (hover) {
        return (
            <img src={Eyecon} />
        );
    }
}
```

Then, you can just call this function from `render()`

```
render() {
    const { item, i } = this.props;
    return (
        <div className="grid-box">
            {renderImage.call(this)}
        </div>
    )
}
```